# Spring application events

Tags: spring, spring-boot, events, event-handling

I have just one question about handling spring application event. There are two next events classes:

```
public class BaseEvent<T> extends ApplicationEvent {
    protected T value;

    public BaseEvent(Object source, T value) {
        super(source);
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public class BaseStringEvent extends BaseEvent<String> {
    public BaseStringEvent(Object source, String value) {
        super(source, value);
    }
}
```

Suppose I have next listener:

```
@Component
public class BaseEventListener {
    
    @EventListener
    public void onBaseStringEvent(BaseEvent<String> event) {
        // intercept
    }

}
```

In this listener I want to intercept `BaseEvent<String>` and `BaseStringEvent` events, **but actually this method intercepts all BaseEvent events depends not of generic type**. Is this expected result or not? How should I implement listeners, that will intercept next kinds of events:

1. All `BaseEvent` events depends not of generic type;
2. All `BaseEvent` events depends of generic type;
3. All `BaseString` events (including BaseEvent events too).

Comment: It is expected – generics are checked at compile-time only. You'd need to differentiate inside your handler.